# send a copy of the registration details to my mail id and recipients mail id using android studio

Tags: email, android-studio

My contact form looks like this:
name: 
 phone no:
 user email id: 
and a submit/register button. My question is after clicking the submit/register button, copy of the registration details should be sent to my mail id and recipients mail id. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly ?Your Question is not clearly stating your problem.

Comment: @Sushrita, 

 After clicking Submit button of my contact form, I want to send a copy of registered details in my mail id and recipients mail id.

Comment: My contact form looks like this: name: , phone no:, user email id: , and a submit/register button. My question is after clicking the submit/register button, copy of the user should be sent to my mail id and recipients mail id. I hope it is clear now.